# Would the kernel change in 20.10 (from 20.04) adversely affect the cureent Broadcom wireless broadband driver on my Macbook Air, now running on 20.0?4

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, broadcom, macbook

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on my MacBook Air (late 2015 vintage), having found the information needed to do so. I am quite content with my setup, but would like to update to 20.10, just because. There may be a kernel change in that upgrade, and am wondering if I will then have to re-do the Broadcom wireless driver installation. I do not recall any kernel change warnings when I got the mac working, but am willing to be wrong. So much to learn about Ubuntu and terminal commands. oy.

Comment: Create a Live USB with 20.10 and boot from it. You'll quickly find out if it works. As a general rule (there are exceptions), once a driver is in a Linux kernel, it's retained in future releases.

Comment: Also check which kernel you're using. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop defaults to the HWE kernel so a 20.04 desktop install will already have upgraded to the 5.8 kernel, which was from 20.10.  It'll depend on how you installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, eg. a install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server, or Lubuntu 20.04 LTS (initial media, not 20.04.2) will also result in you use the GA or 5.4 kernel.  Check which kernel you're already using (ie. `uname -r`)

Comment: Thanks for your info...I'm using 5.8.0-48-generic kernel. 20.04 was installed from a usb startup drive, and updated regularly, so now running 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: I am a little puzzled by this phrase quoted from your answer, "a 20.04 desktop install will already have upgraded to the 5.8 kernel, which was from 20.10"  It sounds like the 20.04 kernel was from 20.10 ?? Didn't 20.10 come after 20.04? I guess I am misunderstanding something. Misunderstanding comes easy to me.

Comment: Ubuntu LTS releases have two kernel stack choices, eg. for 18.04 the GA kernel is 4.15 which is supported the entire life of the product. If you use the HWE stack (the other option), it then moved to 4.18 (ie. the 18.10 kernel), next the 5.0 (or 19.04 kernel), before 5.3 (19.10 kernel) before reaching it's final kernel which is the 5.4 (or GA kernel for the next LTS release).  That's the HWE kernel choice. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack   *same applies with 20.04, 5.8 coming from 20.10, 5.11 will come from 21.04 etc*

Comment: successfully installed 20.10 and no issues, my mac still sees the Broadcom wireless driver, these answers were what I needed. Job done.

Comment: I'll suggest you write up an answer (*you can refer/thank anyone whom provided useful advice in solving your issue; you'll also get the rep bonus on acceptance*) or if someone provided specific help that solved it, ask them to write it & accept their answer. My comments were informational; I hoped for your benefit/understanding, and not solution/answers; though hoped my comments would help you to solve it :)

Comment: I am not unfamiliar with decent manners, but I am unfamiliar with some of the standards in this venue. I have been helped by those who responded to my query, but not always sure how to suss it out, who is saying what. I am also grateful to the very existence of this forum, and those who willingly help a nebbish like me. I probably have no business running Ubuntu, but I abhor Microsoft, and have been getting a bit testy about Mac/Apple for making my computer and software I like obsolete by "upgrading" the mac OS. I want to stick with Ubuntu, as long as I'm able. Thank you all, for your help.

Comment: This area is mostly for comments, really intended for us to reply to you with our comments, concerns etc, and for you to correct any issues, or requests for more information via the editing of your question (adding extra/requested detail there), or via answer lower down the screen/page. This isn't a forum (https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the Ubuntu forum) but a Q&A site

Comment: Is it appropriate, then, guiverc, for me to make a posting of some sort in the "Answer Your Question" block, letting this site know that I think my query has been settled? I depend on the help, but do not want to add clutter or noise.

Comment: Yep, that was my intention in the **suggest you write up an answer*" :)   After a time, (*time for others to write alternate answers*) you'll be able to 'accept' your own answer (*or the best*) answer and you'll gain rep.

Comment: guiverc, my chief concerns are that I not brick my computer, and that I not be a schtoonk in this venue - the immediate concern was about the possible kernel change in 20.10 affecting whatever it was that I did to my mac that enabled Ubuntu to "see" and work with the custom driver for the Broadcom broadband modem. It turns out that the kernel was not an issue in the 2020 iteration of Ubuntu and Broadcom. It would seem that the better question would have been, 'will I have to be concerned with losing contact with the Broadcom unit in coming iterations of Ubuntu?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the strict limits of my question, it has been answered and resolved by the contributors to my inquiry. It turns out that my question was mooted by the way Ubuntu apparently works, and there was no apparent kernel change between 20.04 and 20.10. A thanks to guiverc for clear and unambiguous help in this matter.